# Check whether the brackets and delimiters contained in a string are balanced

Tags: java, arraylist, linked-list

Here is simple code to check whether the brackets/delimiters contained in a string are balanced - can anyone help why wont it work! I'm sure there are many things I could to to improve efficiency but for the purpose of my current tutorial I would like to know why it doesn't work in this form and what the current problems are.

Firstly, I cannot add the variable c to the LinkedList, I have to use the literal value - I have identical in another tutorial and it adds the variable just fine.

Secondly, in some instances it simply doesn't add the delimiters to my linkedlist as per the if statements. the string '(i wonder(if) the delimiters in this) [sentence] will evaluate as[ balanced}' evaluates as balanced but from my code it shouldn't do - Please help I am pulling my hair out here.

Finally, I have had the same error but sporadically not for every string - some i type in randomly for example 'csadlkfsd kljf[]{}[ ][ ]{ '

this returned the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at set07102.Delimiter.main(Delimiter.java:16)
```

and line 16 is 'char c = s.charAt(0);'  and as far as i see this shouldn't be happening.

System.out.println(strStack); is only there are at the end to inspect the LinkedList - if it makes it that far through the code!

any help will be amaaaaaaaaazing thanks guys.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Delimiter {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a string containing different types of brackets: ");
    String str = scanner.nextLine();
    String[] strSplit = str.split(" ");
    LinkedList<Character> strStack = new LinkedList<>();
    System.out.println(" ");
    for(String s : strSplit) {
        char c = s.charAt(0);
        if(c == '('){
            strStack.push('(');
        }
        if( c == '{'){
            strStack.push('{');
        }
        if(c == '['){
            strStack.push('[');
        }
        if(c == '<'){
            strStack.push('<');
        }
        if(c == ')' && strStack.get(0) != '('){
            System.out.println("The delimiters in the string " + "'" + str + "'" + " are not balanced!");
            break;
        }
        if(c == ']' && strStack.get(0) != '['){
            System.out.println("The delimiters in the string " + "'" + str + "'" + " are not balanced!");
            break;
        }
        if(c == '}' && strStack.get(0) != '{'){
            System.out.println("The delimiters in the string " + "'" + str + "'" + " are not balanced!");
            break;
        }
        if(c == '>' && strStack.get(0) != '<'){
            System.out.println("The delimiters in the string " + "'" + str + "'" + " are not balanced!");
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The delimiters in the string " + "'" + str + "'" + " are balanced. ");

    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println(strStack);
}
}
```

Comment: i still havent added code to check that there are the same number of right and left delimiters, but once i figure out the existing problems i can do that easy enough. thanks again

Comment: What do you want to do the split for? You’re iterating over the words in the input, I think you ought to be iterating over the characters instead?

Comment: A StringIndexOutOfBoundsException at the line `char c = s.charAt(0);` means that there is no index 0 in the string, that is, the string is empty.

Comment: As an aside, in production code one wouldn’t use `LinkedList` for the stack. Use `ArrayDeque` instead.

Comment: `str.split` is your first problem, as Ole V.V. pointed out.  The second problem is that you never remove anything from `strStack`; since its first element is always the last opening character encountered, nested pairs won’t be matched correctly.

Comment: Very cringy going over this 4 years later :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it. I'm not sure if it's completely bug free and will handle all cases, but I think it might be close.

As other users have commented, splitting the input string is the wrong approach. You'll need to iterate over each character and use the stack to keep track of what brackets you've seen and what should be closed next.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

public class BalancedBrackets
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        HashMap<Character,Character> bracketPairs = new HashMap<Character,Character>();
        bracketPairs.put('[', ']');
        bracketPairs.put('(', ')');
        bracketPairs.put('{', '}');
        bracketPairs.put('<', '>');

        Stack stack = new Stack();      
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a string containing different types of brackets: ");
        String str = scanner.nextLine();

        for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
        {
            char c = str.charAt(i);
            if(bracketPairs.keySet().contains(c))
            {
                stack.push(c);
            }
            if(bracketPairs.values().contains(c))
            {
                if(stack.size() == 0)
                {
                    System.out.println("Unexpected closing bracket.");
                    return;
                }

                char lastOpen = (char) stack.peek();
                char expectedClose = bracketPairs.get(lastOpen);
                if(expectedClose == c)
                {
                    stack.pop();
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Unexpected closing bracket.");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        if(stack.size()==0)
        {
            System.out.println("String is balanced.");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("String is unbalanced.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers guys there was def no need for me to split I don't know why that was even in there but that was one reason and I think not removing them from the stack was another. Have it working fine now!